# Python running significantly faster than C++? Something seems wrong here

Tags: python, c++, performance

I've been using Python to do some quick prototyping before translating it to C++ and found that the Python code in some cases seems to run significantly faster than the C++ code!

Consider this simple loop written in both Python and C++:

---

**python:**

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

N = 16777216
f_s = 8000.0
t_s = 1/f_s

y = np.empty(N)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

for n in range(0,N):
    y[n] = np.sin(2*np.pi*1000*n*t_s) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*2000*n*t_s + 3*np.pi/4)

stop = datetime.datetime.now()
duration = stop - start

print("duration ", duration.microseconds, " microseconds")
```

Output:

> duration  842000  microseconds

---

**C++:**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int N = 16777216;
    int f_s = 8000;
    double t_s = 1.0 / f_s;

    std::vector<double> x(N);

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int n = 0; n < N; ++n)
    {
            x[n] = std::sin(2 * M_PI * 1000 * n * t_s) + 0.5 * std::sin(2 * M_PI * 2000 * n * t_s + 3 * M_PI / 4);
    }

    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop - start);

    std::cout << "duration " << duration.count() << " microseconds." << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

> duration 1993000 microseconds.

---

The Python code does seem to take a significant amount of time to startup, while the C++ code runs instantly. (Maybe the Python interpreter is doing some optimization at startup that takes a long time?) But even with that fact aside, once the Python code is running, the loop itself runs significantly faster in Python.

This thoroughly surprised me but I can't seem to figure out how Python is running this loop so fast. I even tried compiling the C++ code at different optimization levels to see if somehow the compiler was just doing a bad job of optimizing. The C++ example above was compiled with `g++ -O3` to improve optimization. When that didn't cut it I even tried `g++ -Ofast` which improved runtime to `1205000` microseconds, but it was STILL significantly slower than the Python loop!

I've tried Googling around but I can't find any real explanation... How could this be happening? How can I get better performance from my C++ loop?? I would expect I could get at LEAST as fast as the Python loop if not faster.

---

I am running `Python 3.7.2`

The C++ example was compiled using `g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0` with the `-O3` compiler switch to improve optimization.

I also tried compiling the C++ code in a linux environment with `g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)` with similar results.

Comment: Numpy has its inner loops written in optimized C.

Comment: @Barmar What inner loop?

Comment: Regardless of what numpy is doing underneath, writing a loop directly in C++ using standard library `sin` and `cos` functions (which were carefully crafted for optimal performance) should be at least at the same level of optimization.

Comment: Oops, I assumed you were letting numpy perform the operation on the entire array at once, rather than using a `for` loop of your own.

Comment: @Barmar, That's how I originally had it but I changed it to an explicit `for` loop for a more direct comparison. The results are similar either way.

Comment: You should use [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) or [`time.process_time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) for performance timings, not `datetime.datetime.now`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not using the `microseconds` component of `timedelta` correctly. It only gives you the sub-second microseconds portion of the time measurement, not the total elapsed microseconds. This code highlights your mistake

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0 )
end   = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 12, 0, 1, microsecond=500000 )
diff = end - start

print('Total duration=',diff)
print('Total seconds=', diff.total_seconds())
print('microseconds=', diff.microseconds)
```

```sh
# output
Total duration= 0:00:01.500000
Total seconds= 1.5
microseconds= 500000
```

Use `total_seconds` and multiply by 1e6, or just change your tests to report the results in seconds.

**Note** C++ should win this easily. Your loop has a fixed number of iterations that are known at compile time, and none of the calculations depend on each other. A good optimizing C++ compiler should chunkify, or partially unroll, that loop and use SSE instructions to perform small sets of computations in parallel.

Comment: Hey, don't feel bad. I knew this answer because I made the exact same mistake a few months back.

Comment: Your note about SSE instructions seems to only be true on `-Ofast` on gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/YEYrkt compared to https://godbolt.org/z/x1UbWV . Apparently, the SSE instructions either result in a slightly different computation, or gcc is unable to prove that they don't.

Comment: My `fft` algorithm I wrote in C++ is still almost 6x slower than the numpy `fft` implementation though... I guess I've got some work to do. But I guess if numpy is implemented with optimized C underneath I'm not doing too bad.

Comment: Just for future reference, I ran the OP's code and I got 1.2 seconds for the C++ version and 37.3 seconds for Python (31 times slower.) The C++ was only at a basic `-O2`, however.

Comment: @Justin - To which instructions are you referring? I see SSE instructions in both, though the `-Ofast` version unrolls and calls an approximate `sin` function which enables better vectorization.

Comment: @AlexReinking The compiler uses SSE instructions for regular floating point operations: https://godbolt.org/z/RFk8Sj . The version with `-O3` has no vectorization, although it does use SSE instructions.